# How to get php array value from url?

Tags: php

I send data using header in php through this code.

```
$msg = array( "A", "B", "C" );
header("Location: search.php?sms=".$msg);
```

and my url is :

```
localhost/search.php?sms=Array
```

How to get the sms data as array in search.php file

Comment: you could use `implode` to send and `explode` to decode at the other end

Answer (score 2):

You can use `http_build_query` function of PHP like as

```
$msg = array( "A", "B", "C" );
echo http_build_query($msg, 'sms_');
```

**Output:**

```
sms_0=A&sms_1=B&sms_2=C
```

So finally within your code you use it like as

```
header("Location: search.php?".http_build_query($msg, 'sms_'));
```

Or store it within variable like as

```
$sms = http_build_query($msg, 'sms_');
header("Location: search.php?$sms");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) PHP function. Its not a good practice to send raw array like that in url.

```
$msg = array( "A", "B", "C" );
header("Location: search.php?sms=".serialize($msg));
```

in `search.php`

```
$msg = unserialize($_GET['sms']);
```

You can also use json formats.

[`json encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) while sending and [`json decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) after receiving.

```
$msg = array( "A", "B", "C" );
header("Location: search.php?sms=".json_encode($msg));
```

in `search.php`

```
$msg = json_decode($_GET['sms']);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass parameter with URL through GET, you are already passing it as an array.

But, generally, we pass it as two dimensional array.

We can pass it like 3 dimensional array explained below.

You can pass array over URL like this:

```
search.php?sms[one]=two&sms[two]=three
```

Now, get the value of $sms

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET['sms']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it works:

```
$arr = array( "A", "B", "C" );
$msg=json_encode($arr);
header("Location: search.php?sms=".$msg);

<?php 
if ($_GET['sms']!=null) {
  $array=$_GET['sms'];
  $arr=json_decode($array);
  print_r($arr) ;
}?>
```

Comment: This is same as my answer.

Comment: use `json_decode($array,true);` to get array otherwise it will return objects.

Answer (score 0):

Send data use php `implode` :-

```
$msg = implode(',',array( "A", "B", "C" ));
header("Location: index.php?sms=".$msg);
```

Get data use php `explode` :-

```
$arr=explode(",",$_GET['sms']);
print_r($arr);
```